# I have issue defining my column names for box plot or histogram

Tags: r

I have a csv file with two columns and and 134 rows which the first row is my column names, I want to create a histogram and a boxplot out of it with this code:

```r
setwd("C:/Users/shaghayegh.bayati/Desktop/R presentation/histogram-boxplot")
samples = read.csv2(file="test.csv", header=TRUE)

hist(samples$patient.ID ~ samples$IgA.intensity)
# Error in hist.default(samples$patient.ID ~ samples$IgA.intensity) : 
#   'x' must be numeric

boxplot(samples$patient.ID ~ samples$IgA.intensity)
# Error in stats::model.frame.default(formula = samples$patient.ID ~ samples$IgA.intensity) : 
#   invalid type (NULL) for variable 'samples$IgA.intensity'
```

What is wrong here?

thank you

Comment: (1) I don't recall `hist` having a formula method. (2) It seems like you want to group or facet, but base graphics takes more work than that. (3) Typically, the LHS has values, RHS has grouping variables, I suspect your boxplot formula sides should be swapped. (4) Slightly more readable, `boxplot(IgA.intensity ~ patient.ID, data=samples)`. (5) `invalid type` means you likely misspelled one of your variable names, check upper/lower and spelling, it's likely a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to answer your question if you could share your dataset.

Also, if this helps:

Perhaps, as the 1st column is merely an "ID" column you might not need to use that column to plot histogram and box plot.
You could simply do

```
hist(samples$IgA.intensity)
boxplot(samples$IgA.intensity)
```

Kindly also check that you carefully type the column name